# How can I save a beer when it's about to overflow?

Tags: drinks

Over on the Beer StackExchange page, I just read [this question](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/458/why-do-beer-bottles-overflow-when-hit-from-above), which asks why a common beer prank causes a very sudden mess.

[image]

Now having read the answers on that page, the next time someone taps a bottle on top of my beer, I'll know exactly why it's about to overflow, but I don't know how to stop it or prevent the huge mess I'm about to experience in about 500 milliseconds.

So at a party, can I prevent my beer or overflowing when tapped like this (assuming I am offered a bottle and no other container to pour it into), and what can I do during the moment before something terrible happens?

Comment: @Robert I commented because it isn't a hack (and doesn't require one IMO), and I didn't think an answer of "plug the hole" was appropriate. If not the comments, where can I say this?

Comment: @Geobits The tooltip says "Use comments to ask for more information or to suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." Random asides and tangential conversations really don't really fit anywhere in this type of wiki-style Q&A. We're more like Wikipedia in that sense than a general discussion forum. (actually I would like to *fix* comments so the UI can better accommodate that kind of enthusiasm, but that's a project for another day). In the meantime, that's why we provide chat rooms to talk about whatever.

Comment: @Robert I might have to disagree there. The comments are regularly used to discuss aspects of questions not in the tooltip, and a good thing too c:

Comment: Wouldn't Beer StackExchange be a better place to ask this since they kind of created the problem?

Comment: Avoiding or stopping the physics behind this activity doesn't seem to be conducive to a "hack." We tried, but I'm going to close this as off topic.

Comment: @RobertCartaino A good answer would save the question, I've love to know how to save a beer when it's overflowing (whether from a prank or just opening it after it's been shaken). but without that, it is a bit off topic :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the palm of your other hand over the top of the bottle and release the gas slowly.

Alternatively, give the tapper a hug immediately.

Comment: You forgot the final step. 1.Put the palm of your other hand over the top of the bottle 2. release the gas slowly 3. Punch the prankster in the throat

Comment: Or put your thumb on the top of the bottle and spray the pranker. An eye for an eye!

Answer (score -1):

Put it in your mouth immediately, if pressing your palm against it is not an option for you.

Comment: This sounds like something the "friend" who did this to you would suggest :P... I really can't see this helping the situation.

Comment: yeah, that way instead of heaving the beer flaw from the bottle, it will flaw from your nose...